# firefox unresponsive script after grunt concat/uglify

Tags: jquery, angularjs, firefox, gruntjs, concatenation

Firefox is giving me an unresponsive script warning on my uglified js.  Chrome and Internet Explorer load the page in no time at all so it seems to be something specific to Firefox.

Here is the relevant part of my Gruntfile.js

```
uglify : {
        options : {
            except : [ 'jQuery', 'angular' ]
        },
        dist : {
            files : [
                    {
                        src : [ '<%= path.src %>/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
                                '<%= path.src %>/bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js',
                                '<%= path.src %>/bower_components/jqueryui-touch-punch/jquery.ui.touch-punch.js',
                                '<%= path.src %>/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
                                '<%= path.src %>/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
                                '<%= path.src %>/bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js',
                                '<%= path.src %>/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js',
                                '<%= path.src %>/bower_components/ui-utils/ui-utils.js', 
                                '<%= path.src %>/bower_components/angular-ui-sortable/sortable.js',
                                '<%= path.src %>/bower_components/d3/d3.js',
                                '<%= path.src %>/bower_components/ng-csv/build/ng-csv.js',
                                '<%= path.src %>/bower_components/ng-device-detector/ng-device-detector.js',
                                '<%= path.src %>/bower_components/angular-shims-placeholder/dist/angular-shims-placeholder.js',
                                '<%= path.src %>/bower_components/angular-validation-match/dist/angular-input-match.min.js',
                                '<%= path.src %>/bower_components/angular-filter/dist/angular-filter.js',
                                '<%= path.src %>/bower_components/angular-toggle-switch/angular-toggle-switch.js',
                                '<%= path.src %>/bower_components/angular-ui-select/dist/select.js',
                                '<%= path.src %>/bower_components/ng-grid/build/ng-grid.js',
                                '<%= path.src %>/bower_components/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.js',
                                '<%= path.src %>/bower_components/n3-line-chart/build/line-chart.js',
                                '<%= path.src %>/bower_components/ng-device-detector/ng-device-detector.js',
                                '<%= path.src %>/bower_components/angular-busy/dist/angular-busy.js' ],
                        dest : '<%= path.dist %>/js/<%= pkg.name %>.min.js'
                    } ]
        }`
```

**Points of Interest**

- It is not isolated to the machine that I am running on as the problem exists for anybody accessing the page using firefox.
- If I break up the js files into smaller chunks and uglify into 6 or so files then I don't get the unresponsive script issues. It only exists when I uglify down into a single file or a couple files.
- The problem exists whether I am doing a full uglify or just a simple concatenation of the js files.
- The problem does not exist if I do not do any concatenation.
- There are no js errors in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since posting this I have discovered that js charts (could be isolated to the n3/d3 charts) cause massive performance issues with Firefox while Firebug is running.  The problems even persist after closing firebug if firebug was open while on the page with the js charts.  If you open a fresh instance of firefox and firebug you won't experience the issue, but over time there seems to be some sort of leak that causes rapidly degrading performance.  Again...  This problem only seems to exist with concatenated js code.